# Unable to see wireless networks on HP laptop with RTL8723BE wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, rtl8723be

On my HP ProBook 455 G2 I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with the 5.0.0-37-generic kernel. This computer has the RTL8723BE wireless adapter which has been talked about a lot on here. I have refrained from asking a new question because I figured that the answer would be here somewhere, but it's been about a week and still no success.

Most of the solutions involve changing the antenna that is used via the `modprobe` command. However, when I run `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be` and type in my password, it seems to just hang there and my command prompt doesn't come back. I type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> but that doesn't do anything either.

I then open up a new terminal tab and run `sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2` and get the same result.

When I try restart my computer, it hangs on shutdown and I have to force shutdown by holding the power button down.

The other route I've seen involves first following the steps at https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/. Even when I do this, the result is the same (i.e., the system hangs after running the `modprobe -r` command).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was due to an outdated BIOS. After updating the BIOS, WiFi functionality is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try compiling the kernel yourself by downloading the kernel packages from the official site.
Try installing it using
 **

> dpkg -i *.deb

**

Comment: So you think this is a kernel issue? Which kernel version would you recommend me to use?